# Problemas Selenium WebDriver chromedriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

soy nuevo en esto de las pruebas, pero estoy realizando un test case con selenium en conjunto con netbeans java maven, la instalación todo bien, pero al momento de ejecutar la prueba, no abre el navegador, el error me dice que la ruta del ejecutable del controlador debe ser establecida por la propiedad del sistema webdriver.chrome.driver, la verdad no sé a lo que se refiere, si puediera recibir un poco de orientación se los agradecería bastante.
Adjunto código del pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany.quameraccount</groupId>
<artifactId>QAQuamerAccount</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Aquí el código del test case:

```
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class AppIT {

    private static WebDriver driver = null;

    public AppIT() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void inicializarDriver(){
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void detenerDriver(){
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void testDePrueba() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("url");

        WebElement btnLogin = driver.findElement(By.id("dvLogin"));
        btnLogin.click();


    }

}
```

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Pasos a seguir:

1.- Descarga ChromeDriver de: [ChromeDriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

NOTA: Descargar la version del ChromeDriver en base a la version del navegador instalado

EJ:

**Chrome Version**: 75.X.X

***Seria: ChromeDriver 75.X.X***

2.- Inicia el Test:

```
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class AppIT {

private static WebDriver driver = null;

public AppIT() {
}

@BeforeClass
public static void inicializarDriver(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "PathChromeDriver" + 
"\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://backend.fmkweb2.desa.ureus.cl/login.aspx");
}

@AfterClass
public static void detenerDriver(){
    driver.quit();
}

@Test
public void testDePrueba() {

    WebElement btnLogin = driver.findElement(By.id("dvLogin"));
    btnLogin.click();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

te faltaría esto:

```
    WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeTest
        public void inicioNavegador() {
            // cargamos el directorio para poder navegar
            String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", projectPath + "\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
@Test
    public void inicioPrueba1() {
        // crea un conmutador para la prueba dada, agrega todos los eventos de registro
        // debajo de ella
        ExtentTest test1 = extent.createTest("primer Report", "mostramos");

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        String url = "http://automationpractice.com/index.php";

        driver.get(url);

    }

@AfterTest
    public void finalPruebas() {
        driver.close();

    }
```

Comment: donde pone ExtenTest test1 .... lo puedes borrar porque es otra cosa

Answer (score -1):

es porque debes de especificar la ruta a tu chromedriver en la clase donde inicializas, con la instrucción: `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");`